# How to update Google Sheets with scraped selenium data

Tags: python, google-sheets, selenium-chromedriver, google-sheets-api

I'm working on a python script to grab some data from ESPN and update a google sheet. Specifically I'm pulling the spreads and over/user for the 4 NFL playoff games this week.

I'm able to successfully scrape the data I need and print it to console. But although I'm able to successfully update a Google Sheets cell with dummy text "Testing", when I try to update the cell with text from the web element, it throws an error.

```
import pygsheets
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#URI Data
url = 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/scoreboard/_/year/2020/seasontype/3/week/2'

devChromePath = '/Users/ryanbuckner/PycharmProjects/chromedriver'
prodChromePath = '/Library/Application Support/Perceptive Automation/Indigo 7.4/Scripts/Attachments/chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/ryanbuckner/PycharmProjects/chromedriver')

driver.get(url);
time.sleep(2);

# find the spread for the game
gbData = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="401220398"]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]')
bufData = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="401220397"]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]')
kcData = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="401220400"]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[3]')
noData = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="401220399"]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]')

greenBay = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="401220398"]/div/div/div[1]/section/div[2]').find_elements_by_tag_name('div')

driver.close()  # close the focus window

#google sheets authorization
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='/Users/ryanbuckner/PycharmProjects/NFLPredictions/creds.json')

# Create empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Create a column
# df['lines'] = [gbData.text]

#open the google spreadsheet (where 'PY to Gsheet Test' is the name of my sheet)
sh = gc.open('ESPN Test')

# select the first sheet
wks = sh[0]

# update the first sheet with df, starting at cell B2.
# wks.set_dataframe(df,(1,1))

print(greenBay[0].text)

# Update a single cell.
wks.update_value('A2',greenBay[0].text)
#wks.update_value('B2', bufData.text)
#wks.update_value('C2', kcData.text)
#wks.update_value('D2', noData.text)
```

The error is thrown when trying to update the cell `wks.update_value('A2',greenBay[0].text)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey just throwing this out there. Selenium is fine to use however there a few drawbacks:

1. Can be slow since it needs to open a browser, go to the page, let it render, get the element, parse it, ..., close
2. If the website changes in any way in the future, the script will crash

The better option is, if available, go through an api (which espn does have). Pros:

1. Much faster
2. Data will be consistent in a json format (Ie. the structure of the site/html could change, but the data structure wont (or I should say RARELY wont change)
3. Can usually pull far more data (there's tons of meta data there, like weather, attendance, venue, broadcast info, etc.

So take a look at this code, and let me know if you have questions:

```
import pygsheets
import pandas as pd
import requests


#URI Data
url = 'http://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/football/nfl/scoreboard'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'lang': 'en',
'region': 'us',
'calendartype': 'blacklist',
'limit': '100',
'showAirings': 'true',
'dates': '2020',
'seasontype': '3',
'week': '3'}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

# find the spread for the games
odds_dict = {}
games = data['events']
for game in games:
    teams = game['competitions'][0]['competitors']
    for team in teams:
        if team['homeAway'] == 'home':
            homeTeam = team['team']['abbreviation']
        if team['homeAway'] == 'away':
            awayTeam = team['team']['abbreviation']
    odds = game['competitions'][0]['odds'][0]['details'].split(' ')[-1].strip()
    ou = game['competitions'][0]['odds'][0]['overUnder']
    odds_dict.update({homeTeam:{'Line':odds, 'O/U':ou}})



#google sheets authorization
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='/Users/ryanbuckner/PycharmProjects/NFLPredictions/creds.json')

# Create empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Create a column
# df['lines'] = [gbData.text]

#open the google spreadsheet (where 'PY to Gsheet Test' is the name of my sheet)
sh = gc.open('ESPN Test')

# select the first sheet
wks = sh[0]

# update the first sheet with df, starting at cell B2.
# wks.set_dataframe(df,(1,1))

print(odds_dict['GB'])

# Update a single cell.
wks.update_value('A2', odds_dict['GB']['Line'])
wks.update_value('B2', odds_dict['KC']['Line'])
```

**Output:**

```
 print(odds_dict)
{'GB': {'Line': '-3.5', 'O/U': 51.0}, 'KC': {'Line': '-3.0', 'O/U': 54.0}}
```

**Update:**

Ok found the api with the odds. Again just need to change the `'week'` parameter.

```
import pygsheets
import pandas as pd
import requests


url = 'https://site.web.api.espn.com/apis/v2/scoreboard/header'
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36'}
payload = {
'sport': 'football',
'league': 'nfl',
'region': 'us',
'lang': 'en',
'contentorigin': 'espn',
'buyWindow': '1m',
'showAirings': 'buy,live,replay',
'showZipLookup': 'true',
'tz': 'America/New_York',
'seasontype': '3',
'weeks': '3',
'dates': '2020'}

data = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=payload).json()

# find the spread for the games
odds_dict = {}
games = data['sports'][0]['leagues'][0]['events']
for game in games:
    teams = game['competitors']
    for team in teams:
        if team['homeAway'] == 'home':
            homeTeam = team['abbreviation']
        if team['homeAway'] == 'away':
            awayTeam = team['abbreviation']
    odds = game['odds']['spread']
    ou = game['odds']['overUnder']
    odds_dict.update({homeTeam:{'Line':odds, 'O/U':ou}})

print(odds_dict)

#google sheets authorization
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file='/Users/ryanbuckner/PycharmProjects/NFLPredictions/creds.json')

# Create empty dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

# Create a column
# df['lines'] = [gbData.text]

#open the google spreadsheet (where 'PY to Gsheet Test' is the name of my sheet)
sh = gc.open('ESPN Test')

# select the first sheet
wks = sh[0]

# update the first sheet with df, starting at cell B2.
# wks.set_dataframe(df,(1,1))

print(odds_dict['GB'])

# Update a single cell.
wks.update_value('A2', odds_dict['GB']['Line'])
wks.update_value('B2', odds_dict['KC']['Line'])
```

Comment: The API hasn't updated for the Conference Championship. I'll take a look once it does.

Comment: @ryanbuckner, check the update.  you want feed in `'3'` into the `'week'` parameter to get week 3 of the post season

Comment: also, don't need regex to pull out those values. just pull them straight away or split the detail string

Comment: Ran the code and got an error: `/usr/local/bin/python3.8 /Users/ryanbuckner/PycharmProjects/NFLPredictions/ESPNAPI.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ryanbuckner/PycharmProjects/NFLPredictions/ESPNAPI.py", line 29, in <module>
    odds = game['competitions'][0]['odds'][0]['details'].split(' ')[-1].strip()
KeyError: 'odds'`

Comment: ahh shoot. I have a typo. Give me a sec

Comment: @ryanbuckner, try it now

Comment: @ryanbuckner, actually, Looks like when a game is completed, they no longer dispaly odds so thats why 'odds' key is only shown when its pre game. They don't display odds after a game. So if you want what they display from previous week, atleast forem this api, out of luck, but they do have the upcoming game. I'll search around and see if they have a strictly odds api where its all stored

Comment: @ryanbuckner found another api with it. Look at the Update section of the solution

Comment: this totally worked for me. Thanks! it will save a LOT of expense launching and scraping a web page.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. The line that closed the webdriver needed to occur after using the element.  I wasn't aware that the element was closed when the driver was closed.